# Detect and Blur Faces using opencv and c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to detect faces and blur them in panoramic images (dng format) and save them back without affecting their metadata.

I found this OpenCV code using c++ and tested it on [these images](https:////https://www.msn.com/de-de/sport/fussball/kimmich-verhindert-niederlage-gegen-italien/ar-AAY5uRJ?ocid=msedgntp&cvid=606df8521fe64a409b2dabf8974b5eed&fullscreen=true#image=3). It is not reliable [image: see result]and does not detect all the faces. The detection depends on [Xml-file](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/3.4/data/haarcascades) used. How can I detect side faces? Do I need to use more than one XML file to get the best results? If yes, what is the best way to do it?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
//This header includes definition of 'rectangle()' function//
#include<opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
//This header includes the definition of Cascade Classifier//
#include<string>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   Mat image_with_humanface;//Declaring a matrix to load image with human faces//
   image_with_humanface = imread("friends.jpg");//loading an image that contains human face in it//
   namedWindow("Face Detection");//Declaring a window to show the result//
   string trained_classifier_location = "C:/opencv/sources/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";//Defining the location our XML Trained Classifier in a string//
   CascadeClassifier faceDetector;//Declaring an object named 'face detector' of CascadeClassifier class//
   faceDetector.load(trained_classifier_location);//loading the XML trained classifier in the object//
   vector<Rect>faces;//Declaring a rectangular vector named faces//
   vector<Rect>boundary;//Declaring a rectangular vector named rectangle//
   faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image_with_humanface, faces, 1.1, 4, CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(20, 20));//Detecting the faces in 'image_with_humanfaces' matrix//
   for (size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++){ //Loop to draw rectangle around the faces//
      Mat faceROI = image_with_humanface(faces[i]);//Storing the face in a matrix//
      int x = faces[i].x;//Getting the initial row value of face rectangle's starting point//
      int y = faces[i].y;//Getting the initial column value of face rectangle's starting point//
      int h = y + faces[i].height;//Calculating the height of the rectangle//
      int w = x + faces[i].width;//Calculating the width of the rectangle//
      rectangle(image_with_humanface, Point(x, y), Point(w, h), Scalar(255, 0, 255), 2, 8, 0);//Drawing a rectangle using around the faces//
   }
   imshow("Face Detection", image_with_humanface);//Showing the detected face//
   waitKey(0);//To wait for keystroke to terminate the program//
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `haarcascade_frontalface_alt` which is old and limited. Also, your image has a difficult background and noise which might affect precision.

It's possible to adjust some parameters in it (`1.1` and `4` of the following code line), but not sure if it will work.

```
faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image_with_humanface, faces, 1.1, 4, CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(20, 20));//Detecting the faces in 'image_with_humanfaces' matrix//
```

Check other more advanced techniques, such as the ones provided in:

[What is the Best Facial Recognition Software to Use in 2021?](https://towardsdatascience.com/what-is-the-best-facial-recognition-software-to-use-in-2021-10f0fac51409#:%7E:text=InsightFace%20is%20another%20open%2Dsource,99.86%25%20on%20the%20LFW%20dataset.)

**EDIT:**
This video is also interesting, showing difference between YOLO and Haar cascade method. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkfSqOvJRIw